# Incrustar un botón "Me Gusta" de YouTube en un sitio web

Tags: web, google-api, youtube, youtube-api, google-developers-console

necesito insertar el botón de "Me Gusta" de un vídeo de YouTube en mi pagina web, actualmente inserto el vídeo de la siguiente manera:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8avC3hHNeSE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Pero no obtengo el botón de "Me Gusta". Sigo los pasos como lo indica la API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) pero no obtengo un resultado positivo.

Comment: y como consumes la API para el rate? tienes que usar proceso de autorización de OAuth 2.0 para ello

Comment: Me explicas como hacerlo? Yo genere la API Key desde Google Developers Console. Seguí los paso que se indican acá (https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) pero sigo sin obtener resultados.